# Refresh Token Rest Assured

Tags: java, rest-assured

I am performing some test that needs to have a token in order to working on the application, the token get expired after 15 minutes, I have a method in order to refresh the token, the first time, the token is refresh okay, but since the request are getting simultaneously, some of them are sending the request with the old token. Do you have any suggestion for this?

I would like to send the request with the refresh token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended approach is to use a mechanism where you can have a thread safe lock or semaphore around the code that performs the refresh. Typically you would check if the token is about to expire (offset of a minute) and then invoke the method that performs the refresh. The key is to get a lock and then recheck if the token is still about to expire. The double check before and after the lock ensures your threads are not tripping on each other. Then perform the refresh after the second check. This will ensure that your simultaneous threads also get the new token. A simple scratchpad example of what it may look like:

```
    public class TokenHandler
    {
        private int Offset = 60;
        private object _lock = new object();
        private JwtSecurityToken _accessToken;
    
        public void GetToken()
        {
    
            if (IsTokenValid()) return;
            
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (IsTokenValid()) return;
                
                GetNewToken(); 
            }
        }
    
        private void IsTokenValid()
        {
            // Logic to check if token is about to expire or already expired
            if (_accessToken.ValidTo > DateTime.UtcNow + Offset) {
                return true;
            } esle {
                return false;
            }
            
        }
    
        private void GetNewToken()
        {
            // Logic to get new token
        }
    }
```